# Hide empty webservice tag (jaxb generated)

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I need to modify a jaxb generated webservice. Currently, the result is organized that way :

```
<offerCode>XXX</offerCode>
<options>
    <option/>
</options>
```

I would like for it to not show at all empty tags. I found a lot of question in the other way. I tried @XmlElement(nillable = true) on my getter (can't do it on my variable as another xmlelement named options exists).

Does anyone has an idea of how to hide those tags ?

Answer (score 0):

Found, 
I actually had to put an @XmlElement(required=false, nillable=false) on my getter.